# "errors during apply, please fix and qrefresh" using Mercurial patches

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, gem5

I've been getting errors applying the nvmain patch to the gem5 directory:

```
$ hg qpush
applying nvmain2-gem5-11688+
patch failed, unable to continue (try -v)
patch failed, rejects left in working directory
errors during apply, please fix and qrefresh nvmain2-gem5-11688+
```

I've tried removing the patch updating it and reapplying,  but getting the same error when applying:

```
$ hg qpop -a
popping nvmain2-gem5-11688+
patch queue now empty

$ hg qimport -f ~/nvmain/patches/gem5/nvmain2-gem5-11688+
adding nvmain2-gem5-11688+ to series file
```

Comment: Hi Vansh, please take a moment to learn about Markdown code formatting, it will greatly improve your posts and increase the chances of getting help. Also, try to create a minimal runnable example and provide the exact patch that reproduces the problem so that other people can help you out more effectively.

Comment: a patch is written against a very specific version of the underlaying source code. A patch queue is agnostic of the version of the underlaying source code. Do you try to apply the patch queue against a version (older or newer) for which it has not been written? The numeric revision of mercurial is *not* universal. Use the hash to uniquely identify and compare a revision between different repos